# sudden unknown path problem - site was fine 2 days ago

Tags: paths

Please help without suggesting I install latest version (just cant be done right now)
So Drupal 7.56 civi 4.7.24

This site was working perfectly well 2 days ago...
Today - first clue . couldn't select images to insert in email (double click as usual - no response)
second clue
Mailings: new, reuse all produce "unknown path error"
And url is :domain/Membership/index.php?q=civicrm/a/#/mailing/new

I've tried reset pathe, clear cache, clear templates_c, confirmed url and directory, ssl on and off, every browser known to humankind, torn hair out
Noone else has access to system or cpanel
Ideas anyone?

Comment: Has your file structure changed? This caught me out when the hosting company made some changes. BTW, you are really on some venerable release levels there...

Comment: Well that would explain sudden. Reckon I’ll ring and ask them! Seems unlikely tho’. Reckon old venerable is peeved that I’m about to upgrade to WordPress 6 and Civi 5.5. And wish me luck with that...

Comment: Your hosting could also have changed its version of php - although that is likely to produce other problems besides file paths.